# Create Multiple libvirt Volumes From One XML File

Tags: python, xml, libvirt

I'm using libvirt's `virsh vol-create` command to create multiple volumes. I've started using Jinja2 templates to help with automating the task for a specific application. In my case, it would help simplify things for me if I could use the looping feature of Jinja2 to create multiple "<volume>" sections in a single XML file. However, generally speaking, XML requires a single top-level tag to be defined (not multiple of the same) and besides this `virsh vol-create` gives me an error anyway:

```
$ virsh vol-create default volumes.xml 
error: Failed to create vol from volumes.xml
error: (storage_volume_definition):16: Extra content at the end of the document
<volume>
^
```

(file contents are [here](http://pastebin.com/TGHhfP9u))

Is it possible to put multiple "<volume>" definitions in the same XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. One solution I created was to create my own "root tag" called `<volumeCollection>` and have my own XML scanner find all of the `<volume>` tags and call `virsh vol-create` for each of them found. It's a wrapper solution, but accomplished what I needed.